# jboss varia scheduler not working in jboss AS 7

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6

I have a web app (.war) to be deployed to JBoss EAP 6.2.0, and there's a class in the app that implements org.jboss.varia.scheduler.Schedulable. I have put the jar file scheduler-plugin.jar in my WEB-INF\lib directory. I have defined a "scheduler-service.xml"(as shown below) to schedule some task on a daily frequency.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server>
<mbean code="org.jboss.varia.scheduler.Scheduler"
      name=":service=MyScheduler">
  <attribute name="StartAtStartup">false</attribute>
  <attribute name="SchedulableClass">com.myApp.MyClass</attribute>
  <attribute name="DateFormat">dd/MM/yy HH:mm</attribute>
  <attribute name="InitialStartDate">01/01/1970 00:00</attribute>
  <attribute name="SchedulePeriod">86400000</attribute>
  <attribute name="InitialRepetitions">-1</attribute>
  <attribute name="FixedRate">true</attribute>    
</mbean>
</server>
```

This setup was working all fine on Jboss EAP 5.0.1 but these schedulers do not get triggered in Jboss EAP 6.2.0 on deployment. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

These are no longer supported. Use the standard EJB @Schedule annotation instead.